# How to validate checkbox using vuelidate?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuelidate

I created a registration form using nuxt and I have a checkbox in the form.

How should I add validation for the checkbox?

I am using the [vuelidate plugin](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate).

```html
<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input
      v-model="$v.form.contact.$model"
      :class="status($v.form.contact)"
      name="contact"
      type="contact"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Contact"
      @keyup.enter="register"
    />
    <p class="errors">
      <span
        v-if="$v.form.contact.$error"
        class="text-danger"
      >
        <span
          v-if="
            !$v.form.contact.minLength ||
            !$v.form.contact.numeric
          "
          class="text-danger"
        >
          Not a valid contact
        </span>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <input
    name="acceptTerms"
    type="checkbox"
    value=""
  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I agree to the
  <a href="/terms-of-use"> Terms &amp; Conditions </a>
  <p class="errors"></p>
</div>
```

[image]

Below is the code for validation

```js
validations: {
  form: {
    firstName: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(2),
      maxLength: maxLength(15),
    },
    acceptTerms: {
      required,
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: You are trying to valide the text input or the checkbox? Want to have the terms accepted, right? Your code looks fine like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
validations: {
  form: {
    firstName: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(2),
      maxLength: maxLength(15),
    },
    acceptTerms: {
      required,
      sameAs: sameAs(() => true), // add this line in validation

    },
  },
},
```

and in form add error message

```
                           <p class="errors">
                              <span
                                v-if="$v.form.acceptTerms.$error"
                                class="text-danger"
                              >
                                <span
                                  v-if="!$v.form.acceptTerms.sameAs"
                                  class="text-danger"
                                >
                                  Please accept terms and conditions
                                </span>
                              </span>
                            </p>
```